# couple edge of all hole to the corresponding center by python script in abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

There is a plate with a lot of hole(fig1), I want to couple edge of all hole to the corresponding center by python script(fig2) in abaqus.
[fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6rz7.png)
[fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gagnd.png)

I think there are two steps to solve this problem

Step1: detect all the centers

Step2: detect the circle corresponding centers

Comment: but what is the question?

Comment: I don't know how to implement with code.

Comment: But that is still not a question. You have to ask something specific and show what you already tried that did not work. Stackoverflow is not a place to get a complete code. Please read how you should be asking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and the reformulate your question, maybe then we can help. If you have completely no clue where to start, in abaqus you can record macros as you perform actions. Do that and investigate the code it generates. You can reference the manual if something is not clear. And if something is still not clear, you can ask a specific question here.